# Second largest salary using mapreduce - Output is not as expected

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I wrote a small mapreduce job to find the second highest salary among a dataset. I belive the second higest salary logic is correct.But i am getting multiple output which is incorrect, there should be only one output with name for example John, 9000.And the output is not correct also,Here i am giving the dataset and code

```
hh,0,Jeet,3000
hk,1,Mayukh,4000
nn,2,Antara,3500
mm,3,Shubu,6000
ii,4,Parsi,8000
```

The output should be Shubu,6000 ,but what i am getting the below output

```
  Antara    -2147483648
  Mayukh    -2147483648
  Parsi      3500
  Shubu      4000
```

And the code i am using is

```
 public class SecondHigestMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>{

private Text salary = new Text();
private Text name = new Text();
public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    if(key.get()!=0){
        String split[]= value.toString().split(",");
        salary.set(split[2]+";"+split[3]);
        name.set("ignore");
        context.write(name,salary);
    }
}
}


 public class SecondHigestReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>{

public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    int highest = 0;
    int second_highest = 0;
    int salary;

    for(Text val:values){
        String[] fn = val.toString().split("\\;");
        salary = Integer.parseInt(fn[3]);

        if(highest < salary){
              second_highest = highest;
              highest =salary;
         } else if(second_highest < salary){
              second_highest = salary;
        }
    }
    String seconHigest = String.valueOf(second_highest);
    context.write(new Text(key),new Text(seconHigest));

}

 }

public class SecondHigestDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf,"Second Higest Sal");
    job.setJarByClass(SecondHigestDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(SecondHigestMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(SecondHigestReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(SecondHigestReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}
   }
```

I am getting below exception

```
  Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1074)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:712)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
at com.jeet.secondhigest.SecondHigestMapper.map(SecondHigestMapper.java:20)
at com.jeet.secondhigest.SecondHigestMapper.map(SecondHigestMapper.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: It would help if you wrote unit tests for your "second highest" logic... In any case, all your names are sent to different reducers, so you'll never only the second highest salary with this code, but instead the second highest for people with the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force all salaries into a single reducer by using a single key

```
name.set("ignore");  // Could use a NullWritable 
salary.set(split[2]+";"+split[3])); // change to TextWritable 
context.write(name,salary);  // need to change the signature of the mapper class
```

Then in the reducer, change the method to accept text values, then split those apart, cast the salary, and then compare those

Comment: i tried your solution and edited my question can you please check once why i am getting this exception ?

Comment: @Mandrek you really shouldnt _edit_ your question in this way, its completely different now. Cricket_007 answered your question, most likely correctly. You should accept his answer and ask a new question if you have a different problem. The issue you have now is a very common one, a quick search will likely find possible answer. To give you a pointer try removing `job.setCombinerClass(SecondHigestReducer.class);` from your driver.

Comment: @BinaryNerd  i am very sorry

Comment: @Mandrek You should be seeing Array out of bounds exception... `fn[3]` isn't possible when there's only two values around a single semicolon

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please edit my code it will be very helpful please ? Actually i am new to hadoop

Comment: Your code looks fine. Your error makes no sense to me because you're never using IntWritable as part of your mapper

Comment: @cricket_007 is there any thing wrng in the driver class ? I am using IntWritable in the reducer

Comment: You might want to set `job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);`

Comment: @cricket_007 i will try

Comment: @cricket_007 i have edited my code to and the job ran successfully but i am getting completely wrong otput which is ignore 0.Can you please help me to figure it out.i am editing the code ?

Comment: I suggest adding some print statements to your reducer and looking at the job logs. As I mentioned before, `fn[3]` is throwing an out of bounds error